# How do I add this column into the new table matching with their item codes?

Tags: sql-server

```
insert into [CLOSING STOCK] 
select AOFC_IMS.Categories 
from AOFC_IMS 
where AOFC_IMS.[DISTRIBUTOR ITEM CODE]
           =[CLOSING STOCK].[DISTRIBUTOR ITEM CODE];
```

Comment: We don't have access to your environment. Posting some SQL we **can't* run and not actually writing out a question isn't going to get you any answers. Could you think about rewritting your post please?

Comment: Could you tell me how to add a column from an existing table to another table whilst matching them through the 'itemcode'?

Comment: Can you post DDL for the 2 tables please?

Comment: Please read this [ask]

Comment: Your nickname has been well chosen; with questions like this you are unlikely to get any advise.

Comment: DDL 
AOFC_IMS
Distributor item code : int
categories: nvarchar
etc

Closing Stock
Distributor item code: int
Normal stock : float
etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a table called `Closing_Stock` with a column called, I'm guessing, `Categories` that you want to update with data from the `AOFC_IMS` table

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Categories = T2.Categories
FROM [CLOSING STOCK] T1
INNER JOIN [AOFC_IMS] T2 ON T1.[DISTRIBUTOR ITEM CODE]
                              = T2.[DISTRIBUTOR ITEM CODE];
```